# TortoiseGit (64 bit) stops working on cpt reboot (win 7 64 bit)

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I installed TortoiseGit 1.6.5.0 64 bit and Git on Windows 7 64 bit, connecting to a local git server.  It ran for 3 days after the first install.  On rebooting cpt after a weekend, it stopped running on a clone ("network error: connection refused").  Rsa key used to connect to server works on putty.  Git standalone also works with the same rsa key, using TortoisePlink.exe.

Have tried uninstalling and re-installing TortoiseGit but the result is still the same - no go for TortoiseGit (clone, push, pull...).

Have tried to take out Putty to force TortoiseGit to use its own pagent.exe, no difference.

Would like to use TortoiseGit instead of Git.  Any suggestions would be welcomed. tia.

Comment: Can you check if you have a HOME environment variable defined (or if TortoiseGit, in its settings, defines a HOME where it will look for the .ssh directory)?

Comment: on each clone eg. TortoiseGit will ask for the path to the key.  The path is correct, and I have not changed the key path either on TortoiseGit when it was working to when it was not.  I also have not touched the key.  In theory, the only diff between TortoiseGit working before weekend and when it was not was a cpt reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same frustrating issue. Try to read the debug information from Tortoiseplink:

1. Create TortoisePlink.cmd file in the same folder as TortoisePlink.exe with the following content:

   @echo off
   *path*\TortoisePlink.exe -v %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9

   replace *path* to suit your needs.
2. Go to to TortoiseGit settings -> Network and choose TortoisePlink.cmd as your ssh client.
3. Make something with your repository (clone, push, pull) and view the output.

In my case TortoiseGit was always trying to use one particular key, which have not been assigned to git user. I found no settings regarding default keys, so I just moved this key and then TortoiseGit was able to use other keys.

Comment: So, I finally figured out what was the cause of the problem (at least in my case). I used domain name as a session name in Putty and TortoiseGit (TortoisePlink) used the key assigned to this session. I renamed the session and TortoiseGit is able to use the proper key again.

Comment: You should post this as an answer then.